# Managing queries with URI.js

Tags: javascript, url, uri, pushstate

My goal is to be able to manage and modify query parameters in a URL. I decided to give [URI.js](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/) a shot.

When the page first loads, it already has a parameter: `http://localhost:3000/football?game=This-Game`. What I want to be to then do is append parameters like `http://localhost:3000/football?game=This-Game&foo=bar&fiz=buzz`.

I can't quite figure out how to do so with URI.js, whilst keeping the first part of the param. I suppose I'll probably have to pull that first param into an object on page load, and then reset it, but was hoping for an easier way.

Previously to trying URI.js, I was using `pushState` and grabbed the current `window.location` *plus* whatever params I wanted added, formed a string, and pushed it to the URL

`if (typeof (history.pushState) != 'undefined') {
    var obj = { Title: title, Url: url };
    history.pushState(obj, obj.Title, obj.Url);
}`

I'd like to still use pushState (since I think it's the only way, although the URI.js docs don't talk much about it), but basically have a parameters object that I can add to, remove, etc. whenever I please and it automatically updates the URL.

I'm currently playing around with this code, but the result is `http://localhost:300/game=ISC-World-Tournament&foo=bar` (missing the first param).

```
var url = new URI;
url.addQuery({foo: 'bar'})

if (typeof (history.pushState) != 'undefined') {
    var obj = { Title: 'test', Url: url._parts.query };
    history.pushState(obj, obj.Title, obj.Url);
}
```

In summary, I think I'm on the right track, but was hoping for an easy way to manage params.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [setQuery](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/docs.html#search-set) method to update existing parameters and add new ones.

From the link:

```
var uri = new URI("?hello=world");
uri.setQuery("hello", "mars"); // returns the URI instance for chaining
// uri == "?hello=mars"

uri.setQuery({ foo: "bar", goodbye : ["world", "mars"] });
// uri == "?hello=mars&foo=bar&goodbye=world&goodbye=mars"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use search method as well

```
const obj = {
      game : "this-game",
      foo  : "oof",
      bar  : ["bar1","bar2"]
};

var uri = new URI();
uri.search(obj)
// uri = ?game=this-game&foo=off&bar=bar1&bar=bar2
```